# Typescript compiler fails to check react-redux connect HOC

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux

I have similar code to this one:
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-q0yrc?file=/src/test.tsx 
(this is from D. Abramov [example](https://redux.js.org/recipes/usage-with-typescript#typing-the-connect-higher-order-component) )

but my PHP Storm (IDE) is not reporting any errors, nor provide hints as to PretendedImport component props. 
The type hint for PretendedImport I get is:

```
const PretendedImport: NamedExoticComponent<JSX.LibraryManagedAttributes<MyComponent, Omit<Readonly<... & ...> | (<...>(component: ...) => ... extends ...<..., ...> ? TInjectedProps : never & {backgroundColor: string, sthElse: number}) | (...<...> & ...<...>), never> & {}>> & hoistNonReactStatics.NonReactStatics<MyComponent> & {WrappedComponent: MyComponent}
```

I created a brand new react typescript project using create react app and it all works.

I tried:
 * using the same tsconfig.json
 * using the same versions of: TS, @types/react, @types/react-redux, 
 * even tinkering with webpack, babel and its parsers (even though this shouldn't be related)

What else can I try to make it work? I'm out of ideas what could be causing the difference. 
Compilation of other TS use cases work.

Comment: What are the props of `MyComponent`? What version of TypeScript is your IDE running?  Can you change that version? Are there any diagnostics created by your editor that could tell us what's going on?

Comment: Sorry for stupid question, but have you tried opening this project in another IDE?

I had a few cases where the Language Server in VSCode gave up, and `tsc --watch` was detecting errors perfectly.

Comment: @KarolMajewski You can see it in the codesandbox - it's one prop expected on the usage side - backgroundColor. I tried with TS version ^3.4.5 and ^3.8.3 (as it is on sandbox). I might be able to change it in the project permanently if necessary. Not aware of such diagnostics in Php Storm.